# Could not load package flyspell with use-package

Tags: use-package, flyspell

I have configured flyspell mode with use-package like this:

```
(use-package flyspell-mode
  :init
  (progn
    (flyspell-mode 1))
  :config
  (progn 
    (setq ispell-program-name "aspell")
    (setq ispell-list-command "--list") ;; run flyspell with aspell, not ispell
    ))
```

But this gives me the following message while starting up Emacs in `*Messages*` buffer:

Could not load package flyspell-mode

Although if I manually give this command `flyspell-mode`, it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package name is `flyspell` instead of `flyspell-mode`, so the 1st argument of `use-package` is `flyspell`.